# My JSON data is loading in twice using AJAX, it is only supposed to load once on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using AJAX and Jquery to load a json object into my web page. It works great however 50-70% of the time it loads in the json data to my page twice, it appends the second set of data to my page, is there a good way to ensure that my data only loads once?

my initial thought was to make the json call synchronous instead of asynchronous but that doesn't sound right, is there a better way of doing it?

```
  $('#myResource').click(function() {
$.getJSON("data/preachers.json", function(result) {
  $.each(result, function(i, field) {

      $("#preachers").append( function() {
      var preacher = '<div class="box box1">';
      preacher += '<div class="image">';
      preacher += '<a href=' + '"' + (field.link) + '"' + ' target="_blank">';
      preacher += '<img src= "img/resources/' + (field.image) + '" alt="' + (field.name) + '" class="resource_image">';
      preacher += '</a>';
      preacher += '</div>'; //class = image
      preacher += '<div class="text">';
      preacher += '<p><h2>' + (field.name) + '</h2>';
      preacher += (field.details) + '</p>';
      preacher += '</div>'; //class=text
      preacher += '</div>'; //class=box
      return preacher;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: did you try to define preacher  outside the append and use $("#preachers").append(preacher);

Comment: preacher is only found within the listed function, are you saying listing it outside the function above would resolve my issue?

Comment: i would recommend that you log your `result` in the console and see if that data you are receiving exists twice in which case that might be a server error.

Comment: Try defining `preacher` outside your append function and do all the concatenation there then finally use the append function by providing the variable `preacher` as its parameter.

Comment: i added a     console.log('load everything');    to my function, it runs 24 times(as it should), but sometimes it does it in two sets of 24 so 48 end up on the screen

Comment: word sometimes maybe mean you double clicking on the button .. so try to make a condition to stop double click

Comment: tried the double click, didnt work :(

Comment: maybe try to unbind click event when the function starts and bind back when you get the response...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#myResource').unbind('click').click(function(){
})...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to disable a button after click

```
$('#myResource').click(function() {
   $('#myResource').prop('disabled' , true); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
   $.getJSON("data/preachers.json", function(result) {
     $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      $("#preachers").append( function() {
      var preacher = '<div class="box box1">';
      preacher += '<div class="image">';
      preacher += '<a href=' + '"' + (field.link) + '"' + ' target="_blank">';
      preacher += '<img src= "img/resources/' + (field.image) + '" alt="' + (field.name) + '" class="resource_image">';
      preacher += '</a>';
      preacher += '</div>'; //class = image
      preacher += '<div class="text">';
      preacher += '<p><h2>' + (field.name) + '</h2>';
      preacher += (field.details) + '</p>';
      preacher += '</div>'; //class=text
      preacher += '</div>'; //class=box
      return preacher;
      });
      $('#myResource').prop('disabled' , false); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  here
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of some of the comments, the answer ended up being that i needed to unbind click at the beginning of the function, and leaving it unbound:

```
  $('#myResource').click(function() {
      $( "#myResource").unbind( "click" );
      $.getJSON("data/preachers.json", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      console.log('load everything');
      $("#preachers").append( function() {
      var preacher = '<div class="box box1">';
      preacher += '<div class="image">';
      preacher += '<a href=' + '"' + (field.link) + '"' + ' target="_blank">';
      preacher += '<img src= "img/resources/' + (field.image) + '" alt="' + (field.name) + '" class="resource_image">';
      preacher += '</a>';
      preacher += '</div>'; //class = image
      preacher += '<div class="text">';
      preacher += '<p><h2>' + (field.name) + '</h2>';
      preacher += (field.details) + '</p>';
      preacher += '</div>'; //class=text
      preacher += '</div>'; //class=box
      return preacher;
      });
    });
  });
});
```